# Wordpress page/blog incorporated into static website

Tags: theme-development, permalinks, themes, blog, static-website

Currently, I have a static website. I wanted to know how I could go about replacing one of the static pages with a WordPress page that will function as the websites blog?

I know how to create a WordPress template, but I'm a little confused about what the URL would be? The website in question is www.3elementsreview.com and the blog would be at www.3elementsreview.com/3eblog.

So, how can I replace that current page (3eblog), with a WordPress version?

Thanks,

Marlon

Comment: do you want to add WordPress elements to the current static page, or do you want WordPress to assume control of the `3eblog` directory and use its own theme?

Answer (score 2):

Keep your static site as is and install wordpress in your `/3eblog/` folder.

This will give you an entire wp install just for that sub folder - the rest of your site will remain intact. You can then use WP out of the box with one of the many free themes available.

Your server will look for index.php in the `/3eblog/` and serve up the wp install, the rest of your site will work as normal and serve up index.html from the root.

You then just link to : `www.3elementsreview.com/3eblog/` from your main static pages.

Answer (score 0):

In order to transform regular PHP pages into ones that utilize WordPress, you need to add either of the following code snippets to the start of each page.

```
<?php 
/* Short and sweet */
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
require('./wp-blog-header.php');
?>

<?php
require('/the/path/to/your/wp-blog-header.php');
?>
```

Then you can use template tags and Wordpress built-in functions.

Next time please visit the Codex: http://codex.wordpress.org/Integrating_WordPress_with_Your_Website

Comment: Correct in principle but I would assume "static" site is plain HTML (or even if it's dynamic it's not given that it is powered by PHP).